# Literal value in struct declaration

Tags: go, struct, default-value

Say we have a struct like so:

```
type Foo struct {
  one string
  two int
}
```

is it possible to declare literal values for this, something like:

```
type Foo struct {
  one "foobar"
  two int
}
```

or

```
type Foo struct {
  one string
  two 5678
}
```

basically for some objects we might have a hardcoded value for a field.

Comment: It is not possible to declare a field as a value.

Comment: A field with a constant value has literally no purpose. Just use a package-level `const`.

Comment: @Adrian that's not true, many objects might need a constant field, like a marker. In a Java class field you might have a field like `String marker = "some uuid"` and every instance of that class has that.

Comment: If every instance has the same value, it's not an instance value, it's a global constant. In which case you can just use a global constant. Remember, these are not classes.

Comment: @Adrian sometimes we need markers/brands on objects. when doing i/o you switch on a field to determine it's type. need brands/markers esp in that circumstance

Comment: @AlexanderMills I'm not sure what you mean by "brands" or "markers" here, but what's described in the question does not have a use in Go, and I don't think that's changed in the past 5 years.

Comment: it's not really a language specific thing; brands and markers are used for structural typing; keep coding and you will find out what all those things are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Go does not support literal types (a la TypeScript). Moreover, it actually *can't*, because of *zero values*.

Every type has a *zero value* which *always* exists and is *always* assignable to it. When variables of a type are declared, they are implicitly assigned to their type's zero value.

- For integer (`int`, `uint`, `int32`, `uint32`, `int64`, `uin64`) or float (`float32`, `float64`) or complex (`complex64` or `complex128`) types, this is just `0` (`0.0` respectively).
- For string types, this is the empty string `""`.
- For slices, maps, pointers, channels, and interfaces, the zero value is `nil`.
- For arrays (not slices: arrays are value-types with statically-known length); their zero value is just the zero value of the element type repeated to fill every slot
- The zero value of a struct type is a struct all of whose fields are zero values

In any case, because it is always possible for any type to have a zero value, it would be incompatible to create a type which only allows for any particular non-zero value.

The best a literal type `"foo"` could possibly represent is that the value is either `"foo"` or the zero value `""` (and no, Go doesn't support this anyway).

The closest you'll be able to do is a `const`ant declaration, or a receiver function that just-so-happens to return a fixed value instead of an actual field.

Comment: well for example with Java, in a class declaration you can have a member that is initialized, `String foo = "bar";`

Comment: Go doesn't have default initialization, so that doing things like allocating slices, arrays, and structures (or just composite types in general) can always be as fast and simple as merely zeroing out the memory.

Answer (score 3):

Go is statically typed language, meaning every variable need to be declared with specific data type.

Setting default value for each fields inside a struct on declaration is not possible in Go. it's not supported.

But maybe you can do something like this.

```
type Foo struct {
    one string
    two int
}

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    foo := new(Foo)
    foo.one = "default value for one"
    foo.two = 2
    return foo
}

func main() {
    objectWithDefaultValueForItsField := NewFoo()
}
```

What I did is basically just created a function with name is
`New<struct name>()`. This function returns a new object with default value for each of the fields defined.

---

Notable exception, for object that created from anonymous struct, the default value of the fields can be specified on declaration. i.e.

```
obj := struct {
    one string
    two int
}{
    "default value for one",
    2,
}
```

Comment: well for example with Java, in a class declaration you can have a member that is initialized, `String foo = "bar";`